# I am experiencing some issues when inserting time to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a website for my booking system and connected it to my database using PHP.

Everything works fine, its just when the user selects a time, the time displays different in my database for example if I book a time at 14:30:00, it displays as 00:00:14 in my table.

I can't seem to find out why this problem still occur, I have changed my global time in MYSQL, I have debugged my HTML code.

BTW I am on a Ubuntu desktop 22.04 and using apache2 as my webserver.
I viewed my global timezone in MYSQL but it was accurate. I debugged my html file, couldn't find anything.

I tried changing the datatype of my column from "time" to "varchar" it didn't work.

this is my html code  --->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <title>Tidsbokning för Svanens Tandläkarmottagning</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 36px;
        }

        form {
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=date], input[type=time] {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        input[type=submit], input[type=radio] {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=radio]:hover {
            background-color: #666;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    </main>
</body>
    <header>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <h1>Tidsbokning för Svanens Tandläkarmottagning</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form class="alt" method="POST" action="submit_booking.php">
            <label for="patient_name">Your name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="patient_name" name="patient_name" required>
            <label for="patient_email">Your email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="patient_email" name="patient_email" required>
            <label for="appointment_date">Appointment date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="appointment_date" name="appointment_date" required>
            <label for="appointment_time">Appointment time:</label>
            <select id="appointment_time" name="appointment_time" type="time" required>
                <option value="">-- Select a time --</option>
                <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00 </option>
                <option value=09:30:00>09:30:00 </option>
                <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00 </option>
                <option value="10:30:00">10:30:00 </option>
                <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00 </option>
                <option value="11:30:00">11:30:00 </option>
                <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00 </option>
                <option value="12:30:00">12:30:00 </option>
                <option value="13:00:00">13:00:00 </option>
                <option value="13:30:00">13:30:00 </option>
        <option value="14:00:00">14:00:00 </option>
                <option value="14:30:00">14:30:00 </option>
                <option value="15:00:00">15:00:00 </option>
                <option value="15:30:00">15:30:00 </option>
                <option value="16:00:00">16:00:00 </option>
                <option value="16:30:00">16:30:00 </option>
                <option value="17:00:00">17:00:00 </option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="Boka tid" value="submit">

       </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP script

```
//Database  connection here
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$name = $_POST['patient_name'];
$email= $_POST['patient_email'];
$date = $_POST['appointment_date'];
$time = $_POST['appointment_time'];


// Prepare and execute SQL statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO appointments (patient_name, patient_email, appointment_date, appointment_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssi",$name, $email, $date, $time);
$stmt->execute();

// Close connection and redirect to confirmation page
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
header("Location: confirmation.php");
exit();
?>
```

Result in database:

[image: Result in database]

Comment: Please post your code and data as _text_, not screenshots. We cannot copy/paste/run a screenshot.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I will fix it right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified your `appointment_time` parameter as `i` when binding your parameters. So, `14:30:00` becomes `14`. Change the `types` string in your bind call:

```php
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $email, $date, $time);
```